# Should I throw away sesames with moths?

Tags: food-safety

I found pantry moths in my sesames, and their webs between the sesames on the top part. Should I throw them out? Are they still edible or useful in other ways? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should throw it out, and inspect everything else in your pantry to see if there is any sign of moths, including the cocoons and webbing, and throw that out too.

As an alternative to throwing things away, you can remove whatever it takes to make you feel okay eating the food, then freeze it for a week to kill everything that you missed.

As far as I know, they're not toxic or anything (confirmed for example by [this article](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=10719392)), so you could eat things they've gotten into, especially if cooked, but you really just don't want to keep it around.

That container looks like it might be pretty airtight, but moths can be *really* annoying. If you leave it open and one gets out, you can end up with moths in everything they find remotely in your pantry, and have to throw it all out. They can sneak through tiny holes like box corners and loose-fitting lids, and chew through bags. They will get everywhere.

Comment: Also, a container like that should *immediately* be placed into something really airtight and sturdy, or taken far away from any kitchen/pantry, or discarded away from any kitchen/pantry. And don't open it inside either.